# Integrating Deltawalker for Mac OS X and Mercurial's extdiff extension

Tags: mercurial, deltawalker

I'm doing an eval of Deltawalker and while it seems to be a great tool, there isn't an obvious way to get it to integrate with mercurial so that I can do;

```
hg extdiff -r some_rev -r some_other_rev
```

Anyone know how to configure .hgrc to do that?

Comment: I downloaded the 31-oct-2010 release, however, I don't have the options in my preferences. If I go to "About Deltawalker" it says Deltawalker 2010 Trial Edition, Version 1.9.1. I previously had an older version installed. Could that be the problem? What version do you have?

Comment: Chris: please move the update out of the question and into a real answer below. You can then accept it after two days. That way the question will no longer appear in the "Unanswered" tab. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> As suggested in [this Meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/108987/166517), I'm moving the OP’s answer posted as an update into a real community wiki answer. —Helgi

See below, the nice folks at DeltaWalker answered via email. *Before* anyone asks, I have no connection with DeltaWalker, I'm just looking for a good Merge tool for MacOS. Until now I've been using Meld (also on Linux) but a recent update to macports broke it badly.

> In the upcoming DeltaWalker release
>   we've made integration with Mercurial
>   a whole lot easier. As easy as a
>   single click, actually. Please grab
>   the following download:
>
> http://www.deltopia.com/downloads/deltawalker-31-oct-2010-1-macosx-cocoa.dmg
>
> And after installation simply go to
>   DeltaWalker > Preferences > General >
>   SCM Integration, then select the
>   checkbox next to the SCM you want to
>   integrate DeltaWalker with. It should
>   do all the work for you. Please let us
>   know if you encounter any issues.
>
> Then Help has also been updated to
>   reflect the new functionality; if you
>   need to consult it, just bring it up
>   and search for 'SCM' for example.